# Check Properties of a Class-Property that is a List of objects

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I have a class and some of the class properties are Lists of classes. I wanna now run through all the elements in the List. But whatever I try I can't grab the objects within the list. Does anyone have a workaround for my problem?

```
 public class car 
 {
    public int id {get; set;}
    public Tire attribute {get; set;}
 }

 public class Tire
 {
    public int id {get; set;}
    public double value {get; set;}
 }
```

And here my main that creates some classes and the list:

```
 public class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       Tire black = new Tire()
       {
          id = 5
       };
       Tire red = new Tire()
       {
          id = 8
       };
       Tire purple = new Tire()
       {
          id = 10
       };

       //Create my List
       List<Tire> mylist = new List<Tire>();
       List.Add(black);
       List.Add(red);
       List.Add(purple);


       //Define the car
       car mycar = new car()
       {
          id = 20,
          Tire = mylist
       };
```

I now wanna run through all the elements in my Tire-property-list, but whatever I do I never get the actual object (black, red and purple) within the List-Property.
This is what I tried so far:

```
var type = car.GetType();
var properties = type.GetProperties();
foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
{
    if (propertyInfo.ToString().Contains("List"))
    {
        var propValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(this);
        ...
```

If I Debug and look into the propValue variable I see all my three objects but I can't find a method to actually check them and get their properties again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many problems in your implementation:

**When you populate your list:**

```
//Create my List
List<Tire> mylist = new List<Tire>();
List.Add(black);
List.Add(red);
List.Add(purple);
```

If you want to add your tire in your list, it should be:

```
//Create my List
List<Tire> mylist = new List<Tire>();
mylist.Add(black);
mylist.Add(red);
mylist.Add(purple);
```

**In your class Structure**

Your car has several tires, right? So the class should have a list of tires, not only a tire:

```
public class Car 
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public List<Tire> TireList {get; set;}
}
```

**When you want to instantiate your car**

Your `mylist` is not accessible inside the constructor call, you must set it up once the constructor has been called (or create a constructor that can have a list of tires in parameter):

```
//Define the car
Car mycar = new Car()
{
    Id = 20
};

mycar.TireList = mylist;
```

**QUICK WORKING DEMO**

I did not solved every problem, but here is a working sample (ConsoleApp):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Tire black = new Tire()
        {
            Id = 5
        };
        Tire red = new Tire()
        {
            Id = 8
        };
        Tire purple = new Tire()
        {
            Id = 10
        };

        //Create my List
        List<Tire> mylist = new List<Tire>();
        mylist.Add(black);
        mylist.Add(red);
        mylist.Add(purple);


        //Define the car
        Car mycar = new Car()
        {
            Id = 20
        };

        mycar.TireList = mylist;

        foreach (var tire in mycar.TireList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(tire.Id);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Tire> TireList { get; set; }
}

public class Tire
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

**Note**

Last but not least, be careful with the use of caps in the name of your objects

Comment: cheers for your answer mate! that solved my problem for now! regards

Comment: In that case don't forget to accept it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What about simply

```
foreach (var tire in car.attributes)
{ 
    // tire is an instance of the Tire class
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. I tried                                                   ` foreach (var item in propValue.GetType().GetProperties() )`             but it looks to me as if that gets me too deep into my structure because instead of going through the three tires in my list, it goes through properties such as "Attributes", "CanRead", CanWrite" a.s.o. . So it seems to me it's getting me one layer too deep. Anyone has a clue how to solve the problem?